# Geany: lost some themes after update

Tags: linux-mint, theme, mate-desktop, geany

I've just upgraded to Geany 0.25 (from 0.21) in Mate 1.2.0, Linux Mint 13.

When i open a .rb (ruby) file it correctly uses my preferred theme, which is Tango Dark.  But when i open an html file it uses the default (white background) theme.  Before the upgrade, .html files used Tango Dark too: in fact everything did: this was the default theme.

Now, when i click "View/Change Colour Scheme" the only options I have are "Default" and "Alternate".  I can still see my old theme settings:

```
$ locate geany | grep theme  
/home/max/.config/geany/themes
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/default
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/rails
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.README
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.c
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.common
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.conf
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.cpp
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.cs
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.css
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.d
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.docbook
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.haskel
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.html
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.java
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.javascript
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.latex
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.lua
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.markdown
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.nsis
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.pascal
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.perl
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.python
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.r
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.ruby
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.sh
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.sql
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.vala
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.xml
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/dark/filetypes.yaml
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/default/filetypes.README
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/rails/filetypes.common
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/rails/filetypes.ruby
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/rails/filetypes.xml
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/README.md
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.README
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.c
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.cpp
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.css
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.html
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.java
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.javascript
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.php
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.python
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.sh
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.sql
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/filetypes.xml
/home/max/.config/geany/themes/tango_dark/snippets.conf
```

and like i said the .rb files display fine.

Does anyone know what's going on here?  thanks, Max

EDIT: after v 0.21, themes are organised differently in geany, and a repository of the new-style themes is in git here:

https://github.com/geany/geany-themes/

On further study this isn't a very good solution as my old version had much more "clever" highlighting, as well as a colour scheme which i can't manage to replicate.  So i'd still like to have a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You already found the Github repo where development of those theme files takes place. I don't see them packaged in Mint, so you'll have to freshly install them by hand using that repo as the source.

Since you don't elaborate what you did after discovering the repo (did you successfully switch over to the new version of the themes?), I'd start by verifying that you are actually using the new theme files.

To do this, I'd suggest changing some colour specification in the new files to something noticeable, restart Geany and verify that you see the colour change in your syntax-highlighted files.

If that's done, check whether the errors you notice in the highlighting behaviour only appear in your favourite theme or in all of them. Finally, if all that doesn't point to the source of your problems, contact the developers to see whether you're hitting a bug.

In my testing, however, I see 0.25 and the new theme files working fine.